# Magento OPCheckout.js

Tags: jquery, magento

How can I edit the `opcheckout.js` from a magento store to make it add `display:none;` to an element while moving from the the first checkout-step ( billing-info ) to the next ( shipping-info or shipping-method ) ?

I'm asking this because I have some issues with internet explorer: after I complete the first step and click the "continue" button, some elements are just refusing to dissapear from the first step.

I tried to add `$('#element').css('display','none');` inside the `setBilling` function, but no avail.

Where should I put the code ?

PS: This question is tightly related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998550/magento-checkout-small-error/14000667#14000667).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is jquery `$('#element').css('display','none');` library included on your checkout page? (Take a look at jQuery.noConflict(); [Adding jQuery to Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598431/adding-jquery-to-magento) )

Try using prototypejs $('element').hide() or see [Add CSS styles with PrototypeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10810947/add-css-styles-with-prototypejs)

Are you sure you are adding your element to the right template and within the right div? Try doing a 'inspect element' using chrome or firebug

/app/design/frontend/default/[theme]/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/*
/app/design/frontend/default/[theme]/template/checkout/onepage/*

Comment: I edited those files several times since I've posted the question and I never thought about this thing and I was pulling my hair off with this problem! I've thought I'm still under jQuery's roof and I was so shocked that the code isn't working, cause it seemed logical and placed where it should be. Thanks, I'll take a look right now!